# Using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser url with php variable

Tags: php

I need to be able to include a variable to the url so when i use file_get_html i can get to the specific page i need.

Here is what i am trying as a test.

```
$activity= 'com.google.com';

$html = file_get_html("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=".$activity) or die('this is not a valid url');
echo $html;
```

The activity is what will change when running my mysql_fetch_array. I have tried single quotes, double quotes no quotes and cannot come up with a solution.

I just get this is not a valid url

If i use this, it works because its replacing just the base url

```
$a = 'google.com';
$b = "http://" . $a . "/";
$html = file_get_html($b)
```

It seems to only be an issue when accessing a specific url

**UPDATE**
The above wasn't working because it was not a valid url. when entering a valid url, it work.

However, putting in my real world scenario it says not a valid url

```
$html = file_get_html("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=".$row['activity']) or die('this is not a valid url');
```

Comment: Maybe the URL refers to a non existing page?

Comment: Although it doesn't seem to be the problem here, you should always encode the variables you want to use in urls: `....id=".urlencode($activity) ...`. That way characters in query variables will not be able to break / invalidate your url.

Comment: The issue with the above example was because non existing page. however when i put this into my real world scenario i get same issue. here is the code $html = file_get_html("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=".$row['activity']) or die('this is not a valid url');

Answer (score 1):

i think its about the https of your first url seems like file_get_html having issues with validate certificates